# How to calculate the k-th smallest number of a linear congruential generator

Tags: algorithm, math

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), a linear congruential generator is defined by the recurrence relation below:

```
X(n) = {a.X(n-1) + c} mod m
```

where `0 < m`, `0 <= a < m`, `0 <= c < m`, `0 <= X(0) < m` are integer constants that specify the generator.

If the value of `a`, `c`, `m`, `X(0)`, and `n` are given, can I determine the `k`-th smallest value (`1 <= k <= n`) of the set `{X(0), X(1), ..., X(n)}` very fast? (faster than `O(n)` - based by sorting algorithm)

Comment: If the LCG is designed correctly, it will have a range of `{0..m}`, so the k-smallest `X(i)` is probably `k-1`.

Comment: This question would fit well at math.stackexchange.com as well.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Not for a given `n` less than the period.

Comment: Are you allowed to precompute anything, given fixed parameters ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust You may assume that `a,c,m,n <= 10^9`, because it's big enough..

Comment: This doesn't tell me which parameters can be considered fixed

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry that I didn't include the information about that. The given parameters cannot be fixed.

Comment: Unless the LGC has deep number-theoretic property that can be exploited, your problem looks like there is no shortcut. For typical values of the parameters, the output is quasi-random, which is close to random. By the way, I don't understand your remark (faster than O(k) - based by sorting algorithm): as far as I know, this is a selection problem that cannot be solved faster than O(N).

Comment: You can apply heuristic - checking first l elements (0<=l<=k) unless one of following happens: (a) l==k. (b) X(l) == 0. (c) X(0) == X(l) then return min(X(0), X(1).. X(l))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, although it has both a math and programming component and thus *might* be on topic, it is carelessly phrased and appears to be mostly a math problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, It was `O(n)`.

Comment: @LovePaper: do you expect a solution to exist? (That is: is this an open problem you have just thought of, or is it a problem from e.g. a programming competition for which you know there is a solution?)

Comment: Am I completely missing something or is this indeed really off topic on SO?

Comment: @nneonneo Actually I saw [this task](http://codeforces.com/contest/346/problem/E) could be solved in `O(lg n)`, so I thought this problem might be solved in a similar way. You can see the solution [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/8903) This is a open problem :)

Comment: So basically, you want a deterministic way to compute the output of a sequence that is typically designed to appear random without computing it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not storing the `k` lowest items during generation ...

If `(n >= m)` and the constants meet the criteria for a full period ([ref here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)) then the `k`-th smallest item will be `k-1`.

If `(n >= m)` and the constants do not meet the criteria or `(n < m)` then you need to do a linear search which can terminate if the `k`-th lowest to date is `k-1`.